# How to display modal without backdrop effect with react-modal?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-modal

I am using `react-modal` for both modals and notifications.
I would like to disable the overlay/backdrop effect on the modal. I went through the API and I can't see anything about it.

Here is a basic modal I set up.
https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-ptolemy-g0pyb?file=/src/App.js

Any suggestions on how **only display the modal without the backdrop**? Note that I want to be able to close the modal if click outside of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As you can see from the image, i've removed background color property to remove overlay

**styles.css**

```
.ReactModalPortal .ReactModal__Overlay.ReactModal__Overlay--after-open {
  background-color: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: The unset is good. However, I solved it by passing it in customStyle rather than adding important in the css

Answer (score 4):

You need to add overlay option to customStyles with alpha has 0.
Something like this

```
const customStyles = {
  overlay: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
  },
  content: {
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    right: "auto",
    bottom: "auto",
    marginRight: "-50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am hoping you can prevent this by adding some css

```
.modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```